# how to search "." in a string using grep command

Tags: grep

I have some string which include "." as part of it example

```
VCAT.VSCH.VIVEK 
VIVEK
```

I want to grep the sting which include ".vivek". i tried using grep -iw ".vivek" but it return no data.
please help me finding the string.

Thanks in advance
Vivek

Comment: If an input line was `foo.bar.vivekski` - should the grep output that line or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `w` and use

```
s="VCAT.VSCH.VIVEK 
VIVEK"
grep -i '\.vivek' <<< "$s"
# => VCAT.VSCH.VIVEK
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Bp8PAQ)

Or, with a word boundary at the end to match `vivek` and not `viveks`:

```
grep -i '\.vivek\b' <<< "$s"
```

See [another grep demo](https://ideone.com/0bLZiq).

Comment: One more question.
If i only want to look for "." than what should i use

Comment: @VivekGaur a dot should be escaped, see my answer.

Comment: @VivekGaur If you mean a dot that is enclosed with spaces, use `grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])\.($|[[:space:]])'`